# T-SQL; Combining four queries into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have four queries that I need returned onto a single row. I have tried to come up with an inline view on my own but keep running into errors or very long execution times. I need the four values returned onto a single row to produce an inventory turns report. The formula for inventory returns is Total number of units received/ending balance*12.

Queries used...

```
Declare @startdate datetime = cast(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)as Date)
Declare @enddate datetime = cast(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0)as Date)

Select sum(act_quantity) as QtyReceived, podet.wh_num
FROM [irms_2_5_2].[dbo].[podet]
WHERE delivery between @startdate and @enddate
  and wh_num = 'HM10'
Group by podet.wh_num

Select sum(qty) as QtyShipped, pick.wh_num
FROM pick
WHERE convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
  and wh_num = 'HM10'
Group by pick.wh_num

Select sum(item_qty-sugg_qty) as Adjustments, auditlog.wh_num
FROM auditlog
WHERE wh_num = 'hm10'
  and trans_type = 'as'
  and convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
Group by auditlog.wh_num


Select sum(total_qty) as endBalance, inventory.wh_num
FROM inventory
WHERE wh_num = 'HM10'
Group by inventory.wh_num
```

[image]

Comment: Use a `CROSS JOIN` using each of your queries. And if you need only one row, then you'll need to do a `SELECT SUM()` without the other column

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple way to get there. which one works best in your situation is dependent on your database, schema and the shape of the data.

**`UNION ALL`**

Here's one approach, using `union all`. Depending on the size and shape of your data, this can perform quite well, though I've had problems on occassion with parallelism in SQL Server with big unions:

```
select wh_num      = t. wh_num ,
       QtyReceived = sum(           t.act_quantity             ) ,
       QtyShipped  = sum(           t.qty                      ) ,
       Adjustments = sum( coalesce( t.item_qty-t.sugg_qty , 0) ) ,
       endBalance  = sum(           t.total_qty                )
from (  select wh_num       = wh_num ,
               act_quantity = convert(int, act_quantity ) ,
               qty          = convert(int, null         ) ,
               item_qty     = convert(int, null         ) ,
               sugg_qty     = convert(int, null         ) ,
               total_qty    = convert(int, null         )
         from irms_2_5_2.dbo.podet
         where wh_num = 'hm10'
           and delivery between @startdate and @enddate
       UNION ALL
         select wh_num       = wh_num ,
                act_quantity = null   ,
                qty          = qty    ,
                item_qty     = null   ,
                sugg_qty     = null   ,
                total_qty    = null
         from pick
         where wh_num = 'hm10'
           and convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
       UNION ALL
         select wh_num       = wh_num   ,
                act_quantity = null     ,
                qty          = null     ,
                item_qty     = item_qty ,
                sugg_qty     = sugg_qty ,
                total_qty    = null     
         from auditlog
         where wh_num        = 'hm10'
           and trans_type    = 'as'
           and convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
       UNION ALL
         select wh_num       = wh_num    ,
                act_quantity = null      ,
                qty          = null      ,
                item_qty     = null      ,
                sugg_qty     = null      ,
                total_qty    = total_qty
         from inventory
         where wh_num = 'hm10'
     ) t
group by t.wh_num
```

**`LEFT JOIN`**

Another approach using `left join` and *derived tables*:

```
select wh_num      = desired.wh_num ,
       QtyReceived = sum(coalesce( t1.QtyReceived , 0 )) ,
       QtyShipped  = sum(coalesce( t2.QtyShipped  , 0 )) ,
       Adjustments = sum(coalesce( t3.Adjustments , 0 )) ,
       EndBalance  = sum(coalesce( t4.EndBalance  , 0 ))  
from      ( select wh_num = 'hm10' ) desired
left join ( select wh_num      ,
                   QtyReceived = sum(act_quantity)
            from irms_2_5_2.dbo.podet
            where delivery between @startdate and @enddate
            group by wh_num
          ) t1 on t1.wh_num = desired.wh_num
left join ( select wh_num     ,
                   QtyShipped = sum(qty)
            from pick
            where convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
            group by wh_num
          ) t2 on t2.wh_num = desired.wh_num
left join ( select wh_num      ,
                   Adjustments = sum(item_qty-sugg_qty)
            from auditlog
            where trans_type = 'as'
              and convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
            group by wh_num
          ) t3 on t3.wh_num = desired.wh_num
left join ( Select wh_num     ,
                   EndBalance = sum(total_qty)
            FROM inventory
            group by wh_num
          ) t4 on t4.wh_num = desired.wh_num
group by desired.wh_num
```

**Correlated Subqueries**

And a third approach using *correlated subqueries*:

```
select wh_num      = desired.wh_num ,
       QtyReceived = ( select sum(coalesce( act_quantity , 0 ))
                       from irms_2_5_2.dbo.podet
                       where wh_num   = desired.wh_num
                         and delivery between @startdate and @enddate
                     ) ,
       QtyShipped  = ( select QtyShipped = sum(coalesce( qty , 0 ))
                       from pick
                       where wh_num = desired.wh_num
                         and convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
                     ) ,
       Adjustments = ( select Adjustments = sum(coalesce( item_qty-sugg_qty , 0 ))
                       from auditlog
                       where wh_num     = desired.wh_num
                         and trans_type = 'as'
                         and convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
                     ) ,
       EndBalance  = ( Select sum(total_qty)
                       from inventory
                       where wh_num = desired.wh_num
                     )
from ( select wh_num = 'hm10' ) desired
```

One final approach, that can be useful when you have a lot of contention in the database and you want to minimize your queries footprint with respect to locks, is to create a temp table with the correct number of columns for the final result set:

```
declare @work table
(
  wh_num       varchar(32) not null ,
  QtyReceived  int         not null ,
  QtyShipped   int         not null ,
  Adjustments  int         not null ,
  EndBalance   int         not null  
)
```

Then compute each value separately, inserting a new row into the work table, thus:

```
insert @work (wh_num,QtyReceived)
select 'hm10' ,
       sum(coalesce( act_quantity , 0 ))
from irms_2_5_2.dbo.podet
where wh_num   = 'hm10'
and delivery between @startdate and @enddate
```

After the table is fully populated, summarize the few rows into one to return the result set:

```
select wh_num ,
       QtyReceived = sum(QtyReceived) ,
       ...
from @work
group by wh_num
```

Not that each query could also populate a T-SQL variable:

```
declare @QtyReceived int

set @QtyReceived = ( select sum(...) from podet where wh_num = 'hm10' )
...
```

with a final table-less select to return the final result set:

```
select wh_num      = 'hm10' ,
       QtyReceived = @QtyReceived ,
       ...
```

Lots of different way to do it. You just need to find the one that works best for your particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply define four variables, assign the values to them and select them at the end. For Ex:

```
DECLARE @QtyReceived INT,
        @QtyShipped INT,
        @Adjustments INT,
        @EndBalance INT

SELECT @QtyReceived = Sum(act_quantity)
FROM ...
...
SELECT @EndBalance = Sum(total_qty)
FROM ...

SELECT  @QtyReceived QtyReceived, @QtyShipped QtyShipped, @Adjustments Adjustments,
        @EndBalance EndBalance
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a resultset by UNION'ing them.  Then do subselects like so:

Generate your raw data in a consistent form:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM
(
Select sum(act_quantity) as [QTY], podet.wh_num AS [NUM], 'QtyReceived' AS [TYPE]
FROM [irms_2_5_2].[dbo].[podet]
WHERE delivery between @startdate and @enddate
      and wh_num = 'HM10'
Group by podet.wh_num
UNION ALL
Select sum(qty) as [QTY], pick.wh_num AS [NUM], 'QtyShipped' AS [TYPE]
FROM pick
WHERE convert(datetime, left(date_time,8),102) between @startdate and @enddate
      and wh_num = 'HM10'
Group by pick.wh_num
UNION ALL
....<REST OF YOUR STUFF, SIMILAR MANNER
) AS RAW

SELECT
(SELECT Qty FROM #TEMP WHERE Type='QtyShipped') AS QTYShipped,
(SELECT Qty FROM #TEMP WHERE Type='QtyReceived') AS QTYReceived,
...
...
```